# Issues with Shadows (Followup)

Tags: texturing, objects, shaders, faces, shadows

Yesterday I made a post about how my character didn't have any shadows rendered on it, the person who answered the question said he couldn't explain very much without a screenshot, so here's the screenshot.

[image]

I checked the box that he told me to check and it was marked, so I have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: please show the Shader Editor for the orange material, maybe you use an Emission node, or the Image Texture is directly plugged into the Output node, which works as an Emission, a surface with Emission won't show any shadow